# iMac WiFi Hotspot not Working

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, imac, internet-sharing

I have a late 2009 iMac running 10.12.5 that I am attempting to set up as a wifi hotspot. My current internet connection is DSL (ethernet).

I finally found a guide online how to actually do this and I follow all the instructions, including setting up a password at the end for security purposes. That went great and both my iPhones (5s and 7) recognized the network. However, when I tried to connect to the network, it said I either needed to restart my modem, router or contact my ISP. I have had this same issue previously when I have tried to make my iMac a hotspot (I had a computer exactly like this one before and had the same issue with it, the other one was running El Capitan though).

My question here is, what am I missing? Why isn't my iMac becoming a hotspot after I have gone through the set up process? [Here](https://www.howtogeek.com/214053/how-to-turn-your-mac-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot/) is the link I used for the instructions to set the hotspot up.

Comment: I've had a look at the guide you've linked to and it does a decent job explaining how to do this. Can I ask that you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/288296/edit) your question to include a screenshot of your Sharing preferences just so we can make sure you haven't missed something simple. Also, when you tried this previously on the other iMac, was everything else the same (i.e. location, ISP, modem, etc)?

Comment: @Monomeeth I will do that as soon as possible (I don't have access to my computer at this time) :)

Answer (score 2):

1. You might have been sharing your connection from a wrong connection. For example, if you are connected via ethernet, and share it over wifi, you have to select the right ethernet port (some computers have more than one with USB or thunderbolt adapters).
2. Your network has some type of VPN set up, it prevents sharing. OR your ISP simply deployed hotspot request filtering technology. You either have to turn it off, hack it if you know how (looks like you don't), or just move on and not share your connection.
3. You hardware is broken. Nothing you can do there.
4. You encounter kext error. Need a full power down and restart.